# Spring 3 injecting @Required field as NULL

Tags: java, spring

I am having some trouble with setting up my Spring environment properly. In my `applicationContext.xml` I have:

```
...
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.server" />

<import resource="databaseConfig.xml" />

<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:config.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and in my `databaseConfig`:

```
<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass">
        <value>${jdbc.driver.className}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="jdbcUrl">
        <value>${jdbc.url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="user">
        <value>${jdbc.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${jdbc.password}</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.adit.spring.hibernate.entity" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now my problem starts. If you look at the following class:

```
@Service
public class ViewContactsServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements ViewContactsService {

    private ContactDao contactDao;

    @Autowired
    public void setContactDao(ContactDao contactDao) {
        this.contactDao = contactDao;
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        return contactDao.getAllContacts();
    }
}
```

During application startup everything is fine. Spring does not complain that it cannot create the bean or that it cannot inject the property. However, whenever I try to access the `contactDao` field, it is `null`.

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

I should also mention my `ContactDaoImpl.java` is defined as:

```
@Repository("contactDao")
@Transactional
public class ContactDaoImpl implements ContactDao { ... }
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

NB. This is a GWT application.

**ViewContactServiceImpl.java**:

```
package com.company.server.service.viewcontacts;
```

**ViewContactsService.java**:

```
package com.company.client.viewcontacts;
```

**ContactDaoImpl.java**

```
package com.company.server.contact;
```

**ContactDao.java**

```
package com.company.server.contact;
```

Comment: what is the package of ViewContactsServiceImpl class and its interface?

Comment: @danny.lesnik - Check my Update 2.

Comment: I'm sorry, i forget to mention and what about ContactDaoImpl and it's interface package?

Comment: @danny.lesnik - Check Update 2 again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thins ViewContactsServiceImpl  is being instantiated by GWT (guessing based on RemoteServiceServlet) - so it is not spring managed bean.

You need to invoked auto-wire manually by overriding and implementing the init method. Similar to the code shown below (from this [article](http://pgt.de/2009/07/17/non-invasive-gwt-and-spring-integration-reloaded/)). As explained in that article create an AbstractRemoteServlet that all your GWTService can extend.

```
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    WebApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils
            .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(config.getServletContext());
    AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = ctx
            .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    beanFactory.autowireBean(this);
}
```

Look at [GWT-SL](http://gwt-widget.sourceforge.net/gwt-sl/reference-1.0/index.html) library for another approach to exposing spring managed beans as GWT remote services.

Comment: LEGEND! Thanks a million. Works perfectly.